# Maven build fails for required libraries while executing robot tests

Tags: python, maven, jython, robotframework, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute the test-suite written on Robotframework through maven, as i want to capture the overall code covered in the unit and integration test phases for this I am using jacoco plugin.

All looks good, It does starts executing the robot tests but fails to import some test libraries, like `SSHLibrary`, `requests`,`jsonschema` etc.

I came to know that I will have to add jars in the classpath for such dependencies(in the below log see `com.trilead.ssh2` for `SSHLibrary`) and tried that as well but no luck.

```
--- robotframework-maven-plugin:1.4.7:acceptance-test (default) @ rdx ---
Executing Robot with command:
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java, -javaagent:/home/asr/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/asr/workspace/RDX/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec, org.robotframework.RobotFramework, -d, /home/asr/workspace/RDX/target/robotframework-reports, -t, mycli_help_usage, -V, /home/asr/robot/tf2jan/etc/environments/mycli_env.py, -P, /home/asr/workspace/RDX/src/test/resources/robotframework/libraries, -x, TEST-mycli.xml, --xunitskipnoncritical, /home/asr/robot/tf2jan/Tests/CLI/mycli]
==============================================================================
mycli                                                                         
==============================================================================
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/asr/robot/tf2jan/Tests/CLI/mycli/mycli_resources.txt': Importing test library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named SSHLibrary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/org/robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2/Lib
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/org/robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2/robotframework-3.0.2.jar/Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
CLASSPATH:
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/org/robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2/robotframework-3.0.2.jar
  /home/asr/workspace/RDX/target/test-classes
  /home/asr/workspace/RDX/target/classes
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/com/trilead/trilead-ssh2/build213-svnkit-1.3-patch/trilead-ssh2-build213-svnkit-1.3-patch.jar
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
  /home/asr/.m2/repository/pl/pragmatists/JUnitParams/1.0.4/JUnitParams-1.0.4.jar
 /home/asr/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a help about integrating Robot with maven with regards of using RED Robot Editor. 
Check following link, maybe you will find anything relevant and helpful:

https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/user_guide/maven.html.md

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by adding required python libraries in the path using `extraPathDirectory` tag see below.

```
<plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.4.7</version>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <goals>
                                                                    <goal>acceptance-test</goal>
                                                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                                            </goals>
                                                            <configuration>
                                                                    <skip>${skipRobotTests}</skip>
                                                                    <testCasesDirectory>/home/asr/robot/tf2jan/Tests/CLI/dtcli</testCasesDirectory>
                                                                    <variableFiles>/home/asr/robot/tf2jan/etc/environments/dtcli_env.py</variableFiles>
                                                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/robotframework-reports/</outputDirectory>
                                                                    <tests>dtcli_help_usage</tests>
                                                                    <extraPathDirectories>
                                                                        <extraPathDirectory>/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages</extraPathDirectory>
                                                                            <extraPathDirectory>/home/asr/Downloads/python-jsonpath-rw</extraPathDirectory>
                                                                            <extraPathDirectory>/home/asr/Downloads/ply-3.10</extraPathDirectory>
                                                                            <extraPathDirectory>/home/asr/Downloads/jsonselect-0.2.3</extraPathDirectory>
                                                                    </extraPathDirectories>
                                                                    <externalRunner>
                                                                            <excludeDependencies>false</excludeDependencies>
                                                                            <jvmArgs>
                                                                                    <jvmArg>${surefireArgLine}</jvmArg>
                                                                            </jvmArgs>
                                                                    </externalRunner>
                                                            </configuration>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
```